# e(fx)clipse is not working on linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, javafx, efxclipse

I'm trying to install the plugin e(fx)clipse on linux to work with graphic interface on my project, but after downloading and completing the installation, my application could not import classes coming from javafx.

I managed to fix by installing OpenJDK, the jfxrt.jar file was missing. After installation, the file in question was downloaded at **/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar**.

I added it in the bulid path of the project and I was able to import the javafx classes, but now when I try to run the application the following error appears:

> "Error: JavaFX runtime components could not be found.

I already reinstalled the e (fx) clipse and it did not change anything. Can someone help me? I hava jdk-11 installed and updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you download and install Java from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html it will just work. e(fx)clipse has nothing to do with that. You don't need it to run a JavaFX application.